# Prove that function is quadratically integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f \in L^1 (0, 1)$ and let $g$ be a bounded, increasing function on $[0, 1]$ such that for any interval $[a, b] \subset [0, 1]$ one has $|\int_a^b f(x) dx|^2 \le (g(b)-g(a))(b-a).$ Prove that $f \in L^2$.

I noticed that after dividing by $(b-a)^2$ and using that an increasing function is almost everywhere differentiable we get that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|\int_a^{a+h} f(x) dx|}{h}$ is finite for almost every $a$. But I don't see what I can derive from it.